# What is the brightest star (by absolute magnitude) that we can see by naked eye?

Tags: star, magnitude

Is it [Rho Cassiopeiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho_Cassiopeiae) or [Mu Sagittarii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Sagittarii)?
I see in the [Stellarium 0.13.0](https://launchpad.net/stellarium/+milestone/0.13.0) that Mu Sagittarii has absolute magnitude -11.43!!

Comment: The sun, obviously! But don't think you can look directly at it with the naked eye. Well, you could, but that might be the last thing you see ;).

Comment: No, the absolute magnitude of the Sun is only around 4.75.

Comment: You should see [Absolute magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude)

Comment: Right bad joke. Got it. This is how far I get under the influence of a heat wave ;). My mind missed the absolute magnitude part, cause I knew the term, just didn't register it...

Comment: We should include variable stars and supernovae, right?

Comment: @Johannes supernova?! Of course not. Only stars, this contains variable stars.

Comment: @2000 - a supernova is a highly variable star, isn't it?

Comment: @Johannes From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova): A supernova is an astronomical **event** that occurs during the last stellar evolutionary stages of a massive star's life, whose dramatic and catastrophic destruction is marked by one final titanic explosion. For a short time, this causes the sudden appearance of a 'new' bright star, before slowly fading from sight over several weeks or months.

Comment: @2000 - yes, a supernova is an event in the life of a star, which causes a high variability in its luminosity (absolute magnitude).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mu Sagittarii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Sagittarii) is a star system, not a single star. If that can be included, then [Eta Carinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_Carinae) should be included, and it has an absolute magnitude of -12.0. It's a star system about 7,500 light-years from Earth.

It looks like the brightest (absolute magnitude) single star visible to the unaided eye is WR 24 (in Carina Nebula). Its absolute magnitude is −11.1 and apparent magnitude is 6.48, so just barely visible.

source: [Wikipedia - List of most luminous known stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_luminous_known_stars)

edit: [Rho Cassiopeiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho_Cassiopeiae#cite_note-gorlova-6)'s absolute magnitude is -9.5.